# Is it possible to make pseudo-perspective out of an isometric image?

Tags: geometry

Is there a trick to take an isometric image of cubes - that can be thought of as a set of equidistant points, triangles or planes - and in a *trivial* fashion create a vanishing point -type perspective "distortion" on the cubes? Aka linear perspective, 1-3 vanishin points.

I am *guessing* this could be also achieved by "scaling down" the y axis proportional to the point's distance along x axis when calculating the points of the triangles.

Note: Im not a mathematician, terminology may not be correct.

Example isometric cube image ;)
[image]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_point